# SelectedValue of a dropdown (UserControl) is not getting selected inside a GridView in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, user-controls

I've created an Usercontrol (drop down) and used it inside the EditTemplate of a GridView.

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <eluc:AddrType ID="ucIssuingAuthorityEdit" runat="server" AddressType="139" AddressList='<%# PhoenixRegistersAddress.ListAddress("139") %>'
     AppendDataBoundItems="true" CssClass="dropdown_mandatory" SelectedAddress='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container,"DataItem.FLDISSUINGAUTHORITY") %>' />
 </EditItemTemplate>
```

SelectedAddress is the property which will set the SelectedValue of the dropdown. If I use the same usercontrol inside the normal aspx page it is getting selected. But inside the GridView is not getting Selected.

The code in usercontrol for selection is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ddlAddressType.DataSource = PhoenixRegistersAddress.ListAddress(addresstype);
        ddlAddressType.DataBind();

        foreach (ListItem item in ddlAddressType.Items)
        {
            if (item.Value == _selectedValue.ToString())
            {
                item.Selected = true;
                break;
            }   
        }           

    }
}
```

Here the property SelectedAddress

```
public string SelectedAddress
{
    get
    {
        return ddlAddressType.SelectedValue;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value.Trim().Equals(""))
            return;
        _selectedValue = Int32.Parse(value);
        foreach (ListItem item in ddlAddressType.Items)
        {
            if (item.Value == _selectedValue.ToString())
            {
                item.Selected = true;
                break;
            }
        }           

    }
}
```

Can any one suggest me why it is being so.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you binding the GridView on every postback or only if `!Page.IsPostback`?

Comment: In every postback i'm binding it.

Comment: Where are you setting the SelectedAddress in the GridView?

Comment: @Asr: You shouldn't bind your GridView in Page_Load on every postback, that will prevent events from being triggered and will cause losing the SelectedValue. Why are you doing that? You should use events instead of page_load to rebind grid when needed.

Comment: I've set the EnableViewState property of the GridView to false. So it is mandatory for me to bind the GridView in  every postback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution and providing here the same for others reference.

Inside the GridView's RowDataBound() method, I'm getting the DataRowView of that DataItem and set the SelectedValue of the UserControl to the DataField.

Here is the code..

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(Object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {            
        UserControlXXX ucXXX = (UserControlXXX)e.Row.FindControl("ucXXXEdit");
        DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
        if (ucXXX != null) ucXXX.SelectedXXX = drv["FLDXXXCODE"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you got the selected addresses linking to a data source?

then get the ddlist to link to a second datasource telling it what you want it to display, in this case i want to display everything. Then within this datasource, you need to changed the selected parameters to the dropdown list for selectedaddresses

this is how i did mine with vb, not too sure how it would work with C im affraid, but at least you have a starting point :)

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:IWSRiskAssessmentConnectionString3 %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tblCompany] WHERE ([compDataID] LIKE '%' + @compDataID + '%')">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="CompanyDD" DefaultValue="%" Name="compDataID" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

if you need any more help let me know i will see what i can do